# Knowing magento version

Tags: magento

Its a simple question but im unable to find via google

How to know the version of magento that im using via **CONTROL PANEL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login to magento admin, you can find it at the very bottom in the middle.

Comment: Thank you man !! didnt noticed that

Comment: no problem (; it happens. I wanted to put a screenshot but discovered I had serious issue in my magento admin. so thanks for making me notice this.